# In Razorpay Payment Gateway, the order_amount is not been fetched. How can I get the amount?

Tags: python, django, razorpay

While I am using Razorpay Payment Gateway for my Payment Integration, the order_amount is not been fetched from the model.
As seen in the models.py , there are two methods to get the total amount of the order, but trying any one of them , the order_amount is not sending any correct value, and hence I am being stuck here for days now.

Please help. Thank You

Below is the traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\blink\myblink\onlineshopping\views.py", line 243, in payment
    order_amount = order.get_total * 100

Exception Type: TypeError at /shoppe/payment/
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'method' and 'int'
```

Views.py:

```
#Payment Integration - Razorpay
@login_required
def payment(request):
    add = Address.objects.filter(default=True)
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
    print(order) #order=admin
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=("XXX", "YYY"))
    if order.razorpay_order_id is None:
        order_id = order.order_id
        print(order_id) #order_id=1
        order_amount = order.get_total * 100
        print(order_amount)
        order_currency = 'INR'
        order_receipt = 'Rcpt'
        data = {"id": order_id, "amount": order_amount, "currency": order_currency, "receipt": order_receipt, "payment_capture": '1'}
        razorpay_order = client.order.create(data=data)

        # Razorpay order inserted into database order
        order.razorpay_order_id = razorpay_order["order_id"]
        order.save()

    else:
        razorpay_order = client.order.fetch(order.razorpay_order_id)
    return render(request, 'payment.html', {'razorpay_order': razorpay_order, 'add': add, 'order': order})
```

Models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # total_amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
    #Related to Razorpay
    razorpay_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    razorpay_payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    razorpay_signature = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total

    def get_amount(self):
        return self.get_total()
```

Comment: This line ( order_amount = order.get_total * 100 ) is incorrect , as order.get_total is a method and not its return value , hence the error. So you can first get the return value like " x=order.get_total() " and then " order_amount=x*100 "

Comment: I have done that, after what u asked to, i dont need to multiply the amount with 100, it is already giving the actual value.

Comment: But, now in line, ```razorpay_order = client.order.create(data=data)```;
It throws an error:```Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable```

Comment: client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, receipt=order_receipt, notes=notes)

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Now, The popup window shows an error, `Oops! Something went wrong.
Invalid amount (should be passed in integer paise. Minimum value is 100 paise, i.e. ₹ 1)`.
The window is not being opened.
While order_amount=824350

Comment: try casting order_amount to int like int(order_amount)

Comment: @PavanKumarTS I ve typecasted here `client.order.create(amount=int(order_amount)`, since, We cannot typecast on function call

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Still, the gateway is not being open

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your total price field in to integer field like this

```
total_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

or change it in your views to integer field then multiply it with 100

```
total_price = request.POST.get('paying_price')
total_item_price = json.loads(total_price)#for changing float field into integers
```

then

```
amount=total_item_price*100
```

because razorpay can not understand float field as value so you have to change it acc to your need this may help

Comment: Actually, in the models , I've commented out the total_amount field. I am not using it. 
How can i use request.POST, since i am not taking into form values?